# How to split page into 4 equal parts using two container divs?

Tags: html, css-float, containers, equals

I am designing a webpage that needs to be split into 4 equal DIVs. This would be easy if I didn't also need to overlap text onto two of these DIVs. So, I have decided the best route would be to stack two container DIVs on top of each other, each with a width of 100% and height of 50%. Then, I would split these into two DIV classes, each with a height of 100% width of 50%, thus giving me 2 DIVs per container DIV, which are 2 in number.

My current CSS:

```
    #collectionsTop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .topRight {
    background-color:red;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    .topLeft {
    background-color:blue;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    #collectionsBottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .bottomRight {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    .bottomLeft {
    background-color:green;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
    <div id="collectionsTop">
        <div class="topRight"><img src="http://www.solomovies.ch/uploads/blog/lorem-ipsum-1440x900-text-on.jpg"></div>
        <div class="topLeft"><img src="http://www.solomovies.ch/uploads/blog/lorem-ipsum-1440x900-text-on.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="collectionsBottom">
        <div class="bottomRight"><img src="http://www.solomovies.ch/uploads/blog/lorem-ipsum-1440x900-text-on.jpg"></div>
        <div class="bottomLeft"><img src="http://www.solomovies.ch/uploads/blog/lorem-ipsum-1440x900-text-on.jpg"></div>
     </div>
```

Apparently, none of the above works in any capacity at all, displaying the images in their full resolution, not floated, and in no way limited by their parent DIVs. I have no idea why. Please help.

Comment: Did you set: `html, body { height: 100% }`?

Comment: No, but adding it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed - `clear:both` in the css of topLeft , topRight elements

**idea =>** `clear:both;` - No floating elements allowed on the left or the right side of a specified element ,

hence in your case also similar thing is happening,

check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4q4Jz/

**update:**
now check the fiddle.. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5mwBa/)

Comment: I'm still getting four images stacked on top of each other in one column instead of two images stacked on top of each other in two columns.

Comment: Your updated jsFiddle appears to be correct. Now to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

remove all the `clear:both;
and try it.

`